# How to evaluate variable contribution to a prediction

Tags: logistic, model-selection, importance

I need to produce a logistic regression model that:

1. Gives a ranked list of the most important factors
2. Allows you to break out most important factors for each new observation scored

Given that I'm dealing with a high level of correlation between the features, using standardized coefficients to evaluate importance is not feasible.

My thought was to use a relative importance measure from the r `relaimpo` package to satisfy requirement number 1. This doesn't seem to satisfy the second requirement since relative importance measures seem to be at the model level.

Does anyone know of any recommended reading for breaking these relative importance measures out to the individual prediction level?

Comment: Given high multicollinearity, the question is how you think this could even be possible.

Comment: Shapely value regressions are supposed to be robust to multicollinearity, no? See Ulrike Gromping's work.

Comment: Do you mean "Shapley"?

Comment: Yep, sorry for the typo. Shapley it is.